# Given 2 random variables a, b both uniformly distributed variables between [0, 1], what is the likelihood a*b<0.5?

Tags: probability

I have 2 independent random variables, a and b, both are uniformed distributed between [0, 1]

what will be the likelihood of a*b<0.5  (the product of a and b less than 0.5)?

it looks like an integration problem, does anyone have a clue?

thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you mean probability rather than likelihood. Is a*b the product of a and b?  You need to know whether or not a and b are independent.  If a and b are independent and you are asking about the product the answer is very simple.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I edited the post to clarify it. Could you help to let me know how should I look at this problem?

Comment: Okay then since they are independent you can get the proper answer by integrating over the correct region..  The answer is not as simple as I suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Another condition is needed: Correlation between a and b. Assume a and b are independent. The area with ab >= 0.5 is

$\int_{0.5}^1\int_{0.5/x}^1dydx$

$=\int_{0.5}^1 (1-\frac{0.5}x) dx $

$= 1 - 0.5  - 0.5(\ln(1) - \ln (0.5))$

$=0.153426$

So $\Pr(ab<0.5) = 1 - 0.153426 = 0.846574$ under the assumption that a and b are independent.

Another approach:
In [0,1]x[0,1], ab < 1 for sure excerpt [0.5,1]x[0.5,1]. So $\Pr(ab<0.50) = 0.75$ + the area with ab< 0.5 in [0.5,1]x[0.5,1].

the area with ab< 0.5 in [0.5,1]x[0.5,1] =

$\int_{0.5}^1\int_{0.5}^{0.5/x}dydx$

$=\int_{0.5}^1 (\frac{0.5}x - 0.5) dx $

$= 0.5\left\{\ln(1) - \ln (0.5) -1 + 0.5\right\}$

$=0.096574$

Therefore, $\Pr(ab<0) = 0.75 +0.096574 = 0.846574$

Comment: Let's check this.  (1) Since $\log(a)$ and $\log(b)$ have exponential distributions, $-\log(ab)$ has a Gamma$(2)$ distribution.  *Ergo*, the answer is the tail probability of that distribution starting at $\log(2)$. Compute it (*.e.g*) as `pgamma(log(2)), 2, lower.tail=FALSE)` in `R` to obtain $0.8465736$. (2) Run a simulation, such as `n <- 1e5; mean(runif(n)*runif(n) < 1/2)`. I obtain $0.847$ with a standard error of $0.0011$. Both checks disagree with your answer.  Try $1-0.153426$ instead :-).

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the determination that a certain area is 0.75 and contributes to the product being less than 1/2.

Comment: According to your suggestion, I got the correct answer this time. I will try to figure out what is wrong last time. Thank you.

Comment: +1 Thank you for looking at this!  I'm leaving my first comment up because it confirms your answer.

Comment: Thank you. The first approach also works, but I made a numerical mistake. After I correct it, the result is correct also.

Comment: @a_statistician try searching https://meta.stackexchange.com for "general" issues and https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com for ones specific to our site (though you can also find some general help there). If it doesn't turn up what you need, and a google search of the meta sites also doesn't turn up anything  you can post a meta question to one or the other. For pasting in graphs, see the image tool in the top margin of your answer-box when you're editing (it looks like a picture the sun or moon over a mountain). ... ctd

Comment: ctd... Also try clicking on the ?-in-a-circle icon at the top right of the edit window and then clicking the link to "[advanced help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help)". If you haven't looked at meta, it's where most of the discussion about how the site runs goes on. We have over 1000 questions on our meta, and there are over 80,000 on the network's meta site. Some other information can be found in the [help]