# Probability two Rvs X and Y are both less than fixed z element of R given region

Tags: self-study, joint-distribution

Let T be a triangular region with vertices (0,0), (1,0), (0,1) on xy plane. Let X and Y be RVs which have joint uniform distribution on T.
For any fixed z element of R, calculate probability X and Y are both less than or equal to z.

I know that f(x,y) = 1/(area(T)) when (x,y) element of T,
                     0           otherwise.
I don't really know how to start it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the fourth vertex, (1,1)?  We need to know this to see if the region T is rectangular or not.

Comment: I answered the same question days ago: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/277406/given-2-random-variables-a-b-both-uniformly-distributed-variables-between-0-1/277413#277413

Comment: The question is a little different and so is the answer.  As a hint T is a square and hence X and Y are independent and uniform on [0,1].  So what is the integral of the joint density on the square for X greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to r  and the same for Y?

Comment: I see. This is easier than that one.

Comment: The region T is triangular with vertices (0,0), (1,0), (0,1). Also it says let Z be another RV with uniform distribution on (0,1) which is indep of X and Y. I did not think this was relevant to this part of the question

Comment: **Draw the picture.**  The rest is elementary geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a triangle as you described. The area is 0.5. So the CDF of (X,Y) is f(x,y) = 2. From that graph you can see when z < 0.5, max(x, y) < z is a square with area $z^2$, so $\Pr(\max(X,Y)<z) = 2z^2$. For z > 0.5, the square is too big, need to minus that extra triangle. The area of that triangle is $2z^2-2z+0.5$. So $\Pr(\max(X,Y)<z) = 4z - 2z^2 -1$.

If you consider Z as random variable, $\Pr(\max(X,Y)<Z) = \int_0^{0.5}2z^2f(z)dz+\int_{0.5}^1(4z - 2z^2 -1)f(z)dz$ where $f(z)$ is pdf of $Z$.

Comment: Thanks again! For when Z is a RV how are you getting that? Are you using the conditioning density formula and using the fact Z is independent?

Comment: Think this question in the 3 dimensional space. One unit cubic. Find X-Y face, cut through X + Y =1. You will get the half cubic with f(x,y,z) = 2. $\Pr(\max(X,Y)<Z)$ is the volume of the points meet the condition $\max(X,Y)<Z$ in that half cubic. So calculating prob. = calculating volume * 2 = triple integral. $\Pr(\max(X,Y)<z)$ is the results of double integral on x and y and times 2. The final step is integral on z from 0 to 1. I hope you can understand my reasoning.